# I want to get all links that point to an image, using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to get all links that point to an image. Is there an easier way than the following?

```
$("a[href$=.jpg],a[href$=.jpeg],a[href$=.png]");
```

Thanks
Jean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `.filter` function:

```
$('a').filter(function() {
    return /\.(png|gif|jpg|jpeg)$/i.test(this.href);
});
```

Comment: +1 Just make sure to test against the end of the string, so add a dollar sign: `/\.(png|gif|jpg|jpeg)$/`